# filter() es5 react js

Tags: массивы, reactjs, filter

как я могу отфильтровать массив от большему к меньшему?

Есть многомерный массив и его надо отфильтровать от большего к меньшему, по определенному параметру 'Popular'. данные в popular: 5 => идут в числовом формате.

allBooks.filter(book => book.Popular > 0);
Я видимо делаю что-то не то, пробовал методом sort() но он мутирует исходный массив, а мне этого никак нельзя делать

Comment: если не нужно мутировать исходный массив - просто сделай его копию, перед вызовом sort, например вызвав метод `slice`

Comment: спасибо) это помогло.
правда я забыл у sort()-a сделать if(){return}if(){return}retunt
но это мой косяк:)